How do you find cheap cabinets?
I am looking for as new as possible cabinets, but can't afford to buy from retailers or get them custom-made. I am on a tight budget and thought about buying from estate sales and Habitat for Humanity. Any other places to look for somewhat new cabinets besides FB, eBay, and Craigslist?

This sounds a lot like a spam question.  On the slight chance it is not I will give you a chance to edit the question before flagging it as spam.

In ye olden times (24 years ago) I redid my kitchen using Mills Pride cabinets from Home Depot. Nearly every "standard" cabinet was available by mixing and matching various flat-pack parts. Not the absolute greatest, but sturdy and functional (and mostly still working fine today). I made two cabinets myself out of matching boards for odd-sized parts of my kitchen. When I checked a few years ago they were gone. But now it looks like they are back, but (at least locally - Maryland) ship-to-store and not all stocked in the store like it used to be. But that may be worth looking into.

@crip659 You may be right with a username of CABINETFINDER.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   I am giving OP some leeway, since it might be a real question that might be closed as shopping instead of flagging for spam.

Make friends with junk haulers/ demolition contractors. They take apart kitchens regularly and for the right price, they can take them apart without smashing the crap out of them. You'd have to be patient, though.

As new as possible and also cheap...   seconds from a manufacturer perhaps. do you also want them to match and to fit your room? but seriously  demolition yards have house parts cheap.

I am genuinely trying to find cabinets. Everything is expensive now, and I can't afford most of home renovation items. Thought about doing DIY cabinets on the weekends.

Home depot is the cheapest option to go for compared to other retailers. But I heard their quality doesn't last long. True?

Are you trying to remodel your own home?

Parts of it, but the kitchen is the main $$$ spender.

Give a man a fish, he eats for a day. Teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime. If you invest in a second-hand table saw and a few other simple tools, you could build your own new custom cabinets at a fraction of the cost of anything you could buy. There are a ton of resources online to help you learn.

Agree, though time is worth something, and a kitchen worth of cabinets takes time. (If you go down this route, look online for doors and drawers — they’re pretty impressive.)
